# Make pandoc ignore css style class

Tags: html, css, markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to convert an HTML file to Markdown using Pandoc, but I'm having a hard time finding the correct options.

I would like convert the entire HTML file to the simplest Markdown possible. That is, no `<div>` tags and no CSS styling in curly brackets. However, when I input the following HTML to pandoc by calling `pandoc -f html -t markdown reduced.html -o res.md`:

```
<div class="section-content">
<div class="section-inner sectionLayout--insetColumn">
    <h3 name="2ee9" id="2ee9" class="graf graf--h3 graf--leading graf--title">Post Title</h3>
    <p name="021f" id="021f" class="graf graf--p graf-after--h3">Preamble <a href="https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users/4397/seanny123?tab=questions" data-href="https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users/4397/seanny123?tab=questions" class="markup--anchor markup--p-anchor" rel="noopener" target="_blank">link</a> and conclusion.</p>
</div>
```

I get the following Markdown output with all the things I'd like to ignore:

```
<div class="section-content">

<div class="section-inner sectionLayout--insetColumn">

### Post Title {#2ee9 .graf .graf--h3 .graf--leading .graf--title name="2ee9"}

Preamble
[link](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users/4397/seanny123?tab=questions){.markup--anchor
.markup--p-anchor} and conclusion.

</div>

</div>
```

I tried reading the Pandoc Markdown docs, but I couldn't find any indication of what parameters I should be using.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use `pandoc -f html -t markdown_github-raw_html reduced.html -o res.md` it solves the problem.

- `markdown_github` reduces the set of outputs to ignore the CSS
- `-raw_html` removes the `raw_html` extension, which fixes the links

Comment: However this removes tables. Is there another pandoc option to remove only styles such as `{style="color: #ff6600;"}` introduced by pandoc during the conversion from html.